# How would one locate following object [ul, li] in selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium

Could you help me in figuring out how to proceed with locating "new" using selenium webdriver in Java.

Code Snippet:

```
<ul class="ms-crm-CommandBar-Menu"> 
<li tabindex="-1" class="ms-crm-CommandBarItem ms-crm-CommandBar-Menu ms-crm-CommandBar-Button" title="New Create a new Account record." id="account|NoRelationship|HomePageGrid|Mscrm.HomepageGrid.account.NewRecord" command="account|NoRelationship|HomePageGrid|Mscrm.NewRecordFromGrid" style="white-space: pre-line; display: inline-block;"><span tabindex="-1" class="ms-crm-CommandBar-Button ms-crm-Menu-Label" style="max-width:200px"><a tabindex="0" class="ms-crm-Menu-Label" onclick="return false"><img tabindex="-1" class="ms-crm-ImageStrip-New_16 ms-crm-commandbar-image16by16" src="/_imgs/imagestrips/transparent_spacer.gif" style="vertical-align:top" alt="New"> <span tabindex="-1" class="ms-crm-CommandBar-Menu" style="max-width:150px" command="account|NoRelationship|HomePageGrid|Mscrm.NewRecordFromGrid"> New </span> </a> </span> </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I'm using C# but shouldn't make much difference.*

The easiest would be using a `CssSelector`. It's a bit verbose in this case, but that doesn't matter:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span[command=\"account|NoRelationship|HomePageGrid|Mscrm.NewRecordFromGrid\"]"));
```

This will find the `span` element which contains nothing but the text you want. Assuming the command is unique on the page, otherwise you'll need to refine.

Alternatively you can use XPath to achieve the same:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@command='account|NoRelationship|HomePageGrid|Mscrm.NewRecordFromGrid']");
```

Comment: I used click operation ahead of your given command but it's not clicking. So driver is able to find the element, which is a success! but then possibly we need to play with certain ul and/or li? Please advise.

Comment: Can you post a link to the full HTML page and also show your code?

Comment: This is a hidden element. How do i proceed?

Comment: You can't click a hidden element with Selenium.

Comment: Please lead me to a solution. It's pretty necessary.

Comment: You can try to trigger a click using javascript through selenium. There are plenty of questions about this on StackOverflow.